# Visual Studio for macOS doesn't show connected android device or android virtual devices

Tags: visual-studio, android-sdk-tools, macos-ventura

I'm having a trouble with my Visual Studio 17.5.6 (build 3). When I want to run or debug my Maui project on my physical device, the upper menu shows only iOS simulators. In Android studio for a Kotlin project works everything fine.
My pixel phone has also allowed USB debugging and wireless debugging.

[image]

[image]

I tried to reinstall VS, update Android SDK Tools, remove and add new virtual device,... but nothing helps. I have a Macbook M1 (Ventura 13.3.1) and also installed Xcode 14.3.1.

Answer (score 0):

After many reinstalls and searching for answers, I tried an alternative and installed Rider IDE. Unlike Visual Studio, it shows Android/iOS emulator devices and physical device. It's not the best solution but at least something.